# Writing regular expression to skip a line if specific set of characters are present?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex in python to parse a file having contents like this :-

```
static const PropertyID PROPERTY_X = 10225;
//static const PropertyID PROPERTY_Y = 10226;
   //static const PropertyID PROPERTY_Z = 10227;
```

I want to extract the property name and number for only non commented properties. 
This is the expression I wrote

```
tuples = re.findall(r"[^/]*static[ \t]*const[ \t]*PropertyID[ \t]*(\w+)[ \t]*=[ \t]*(\d+).*",fileContents)
```

where fileContents has the data of file as string.

But this regex is even matching the commented(lines with //) lines.
How to make it avoid matching the commented lines.

Comment: Why use regexps for this? My usual aproach for this is "for line in open(filename): line = line.split('//')[0]" followed by the actual processing of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify that, after the start of the line, you only want spaces before the first `static`:

```
tuples = re.findall(r"^\s*static[ \t]*const[ \t]*PropertyID[ \t]*(\w+)[ \t]*=[ \t]*(\d+).*",fileContents)
```

Comment: I left your regex pretty much untouched, but it could be more concise.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
r"(?m)^(?!//)static\s+const\s+PropertyID\s+(\S+)\s+=\s+(\d+);"
```

A couple notes.

^ matches beginning of line

(?!//) is a negative lookahead, asserting that it is NOT followed by //

\s is any space character

\S is any non-space character

Answer (score 0):

If you're parsing C code, you can use something like [pycparser](http://code.google.com/p/pycparser/).
Regular expressions aren't suited (or possible) to parse any programming language.

Alternatively, I think this code is simpler for what you're doing:

```
import re
string = "   //static const PropertyID PROPERTY_Z = 10227;"
results = re.split("\s*",string)
#results = ['//static', 'const', 'PropertyID', 'PROPERTY_Z', '=', '10227;']

if results[0].startswith("\\") or results[0].startswith("/*"):
    pass
```